# How to build docker image, using a dockerfile from stdin with shell varaibles

Tags: docker, jenkins

I try to build a docker image with Jenkins, using here docuemnt. Part of the The shell:

```
# Docker image build.
mkdir -p "$BASE_PATH/.docker"
cd "$BASE_PATH/.docker"
echo "docker version: "
docker version
docker login --username=****** --password ****** ******
docker build -t "******/$DOCKER_IMAGE" -f- . <<EOF
FROM ******

ARG NGINX_CONF_FILE=$NGINX_CONF_FILE

ENV DEPLOY_PATH=$DEPLOY_PATH
ENV NGINX_CONF_DIR=$NGINX_CONF_DIR

RUN mkdir -p \$DEPLOY_PATH \\
    && chmod 777 "\$DEPLOY_PATH"

WORKDIR \$DEPLOY_PATH

ADD customer customer/
ADD mall mall/
ADD marketing marketing/
ADD portal portal/
ADD setup setup/
ADD store store/
ADD work work/

WORKDIR \$NGINX_CONF_DIR

COPY ./\$NGINX_CONF_FILE .

EXPOSE 8000
EOF
```

When running it with bash, Jenkins complains:

```
docker version: 
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   0801b25
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 08:29:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   0801b25
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 08:29:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
Login Succeeded
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-test-scrmv3/.docker/-: no such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
New run name is '#17 ver:0.0.17'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Looks like docker treat the hyphen (-) as a directory not stdin. Accroding to the [offical recommand](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-from-a-local-build-context-using-a-dockerfile-from-stdin) this should work but dont know how. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you use fixed paths inside the image (just hard-code `/deploy` and `/etc/nginx/conf.d`)?  Or else pass them as `ARG` values?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you. I found the reason after that by https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/3538. The version of Docker should be above 17.05. But none the doc metion it.

Answer (score 0):

Docker should be above 17.05. The document not metion it.